# Update the toggle button at recyclerview when the broadcast receiver gets the message

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am working on application that receives the bluetooth data. The application contains an activity and some fragments, one fragment has a recyclerview with some items and each item has a toggle button, a textview and an imageView. i want to set check the specific toggle button when the broadcast receiver receives the message.
for example if the incoming message contains "1" the toggle button at position 1 should be on.

BluetoothConnectionSericve.java:

```
/**
     *Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining
     * the BTConnection, Sending the data,and receiving incoming data
     * through input/output streams respectively.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
            Log.d(TAG,"ConnectedThread: Starting.");
            bluetoothSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            //Dismiss the progressDialog when connection is established
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                tmpIn = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            inputStream = tmpIn;
            outputStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //buffer store the stream
            int bytes; //bytes returned from read()

            //Keep listening to the inputStream until an exception is occurs
            while (true){
                //Read from the input stream
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    String inComingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG,"InputStream: " + inComingMessage);

                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("receivedMessage", inComingMessage);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "write: Error listening to inputStream: " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("incomingMessage"));

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                            // new push notification is received
                            msg = intent.getStringExtra("receivedMessage");
                            if (msg.equals("1")){
                                //Set the toggle button at position 1 to true
                            }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Could you post your whole code of RecyclerView's Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method to set the data in your adapter class. I'm just going to use a generic ArrayList of class Item for the example.

```
class Item{

private boolean toggleOn;

Item(boolean toggleOn){ this.toggleOn = toggleOn; }

getToggleOn(){ return toggleOn };

setToggleOn(boolean toggleOn) { this.toggleOn = toggleOn }

}
```

In your Adapter you should have an ArrayList of Item objects and a method to set the data. I'm assuming you know how to use a RecyclerView Adapter so I'm leaving out the view holder.

```
class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

ArrayList<Item> items;

ItemAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items) { this.items = items }

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.toggleButton.setChecked(items.get(position).getToggleOn());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

void toggleItemOn(int position){
items.get(position).setToggleOn(true);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Then in your BroadcastReceiver onReceive()

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // new push notification is received
        msg = intent.getStringExtra("receivedMessage");
        //Set the toggle button at given position to true
        //Integer.valueOf() converts a string to an Integer value
        //You may need to catch an exception if it cannot be converted
        //You will want to make sure msg does not give a higher value than your item array size.
        adapter.toggleItemOn(Integer.valueOf(msg));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering

Comment: @Jefferson Can you let me know how the recyclerview message will be update for the chat message screen when a user sends a message in android java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885272/how-to-receive-the-chat-message-in-real-time-using-the-recyclerview-in-android-j/66886060#66886060