# How to receive the chat message in real time using the recyclerview in android java

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have implemented chat view list using the recyclerview. But the list not showing the message to the receiver in real time.

If I send a message, the receiver needs to receive the message in real time. How can I make this to work.

I don't have an idea about the broadCastReceiver. Here I am working with the chat screen. Need to show the chat message in my app.

Issue is if a user sends me a message, I can't able to see the message. I need to receive the message via the recyclerview.

In My chatFragment:

```
  private RecyclerView mChatMessageRecyclerView;
    
     @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("Message_send");
            registerForContextMenu(mChatMessageRecyclerView);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            unregisterForContextMenu(mChatMessageRecyclerView);
        }
    
        private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiverRecyclerview = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() + 1);
                mChatMessageRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(getItemCount() + 1);
            }
        };
    
     LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            
     @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View v, @Nullable Bundle b) {
            super.onViewCreated(v, b);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            linearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
            linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
         mChatMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            LocalBroadcastReceiver br = new LocalBroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
            mChatMessageRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(mChatMessageRecyclerView, new RecyclerView.State(), mChatMessageRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
            
            int newMsgPosition = mAdapter.getItemCount();
            mChatMessageRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mChatMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    
     mSendMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String msgContent = mSendMsgInputBox.getText().toString();
    
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(msgContent))
                    {
                        execute(new PostMessageRequest(message, Chatmessage.getmId(),

mPostMessageListener);
                    mSendMsgInputBox.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

My Adapter:

```
       private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;
        private List<MyMessageModel> msgDtoList; 
        MyMessageModel msgDto = this.msgDtoList.get(position);


         @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        MyMessageModel message = (MyMessageModel) msgDtoList.get(position);

        if (message.getId().equals(Profile.getId())) {
            // If the current user is the sender of the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
        } else {
            // If some other user sent the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.sender_message_layout, parent, false);
            return new SenderMessageHolder(view);

        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.receiver_message_layout, parent, false);
            return new ReceiverMessageHolder(view);
        }
    return null;
    }
             public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                LastMessageContent message = (LastMessageContent) msgDtoList.get(position);

                switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
                    case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
                        populateSentViewHolder(holder, position);   break;
                    case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                        populateReceivedViewHolder(holder, position);

                }

 @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void populateSentViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyMessageModal msgDto = this.msgDtoList.get(position);
        ((SenderMessageHolder) holder).rightMsgTextView.setText(msgDto.getmMSg());
}

 @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void populateReceivedViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyMessageModal msgDto = this.msgDtoList.get(position);
        ((ReceiverMessageHolder) holder).leftMsgTextView.setText(msgDto.getmMSg());
}
```

Comment: where you send your message ?

Comment: Chat screen.  For example like whatsapp. If I send message receiver needs to receive the message in real time. I am using recyclerview

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Mainly, how are you listening for messages and what does your RecyclerView.Adapter look like? Are you using a BroadcastReceiver for the messages? Hard to say what the issue may be. Also, are you sure you're receiving messages into your listener/BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @J.Jefferson Updated my code

Comment: Use _Firebase_ for realtime chat.

Comment: @Piyush We can't use firebase, because we supported chat in our database. Any solution to update this in recyclerview

Comment: You can use _Socket_ then

Comment: @Piyush Can you elabrote this. I need to set the realtime message receiver. How can I make this with the help of recyclerview.

Comment: There are a couple things wrong with this code. You should look at Android Docs for BroadcastReceivers and how they work. First figure out how to register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for certain events, like sending/receiving messages. You will probably need to request permission to do this. Also, the Intent from BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(context,intent) should contain your data. You'll have to get the message out of that object. Lastly, you need pass that message into your adapter via a method to append it to the list of messages and call notifyDataSetChange() within your adapter class.

Comment: Can you give any sample for this. I am hitting my api while the user hits the send icon after typing the input. @J.Jefferson So for my case I need to ass the sending/receiving broadcastreceivers

Comment: What API service are you using to send your messages? It sounds like you are sending the message over an internet connection and should be retrieved by using the same API service. In my experience, BroadcastReceivers are meant to broadcast data within your app, Listen/Send broadcasted data between your app and other apps on the phone, or listen for Broadcasted OS level events such as incoming phone calls.

Comment: I am using our own API service using python in our app. But it hitting the RocketChat server. Yes exactly, I am sending the message with the post-call, and while entering the chat screen, it hitting a GET call in the screen. I am sending an receiving only in the same age like whatsapp chat. Any thoughts on this? It would be really helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

In order to display real-time data on your `RecycleView`, there are two things you need to implement:

1. Your data source which listens to the real time data. This could be
   coming from e.g. `WebSockets`, `Firebase`, some message queue, etc.
2. Then you need to notify your adaptor about the incoming messages
   which then updates your `RecycleView`. You would like to update the `RecycleView` on only with the new messages and not the entire list each time a message is received. For
   that you would use the `ListAdaptor` and `DiffUtil.ItemCallback`. Here is a nice tutorial explaining how to manage `RecycleView` updates (explained with Kotlin): https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding/#0

Comment: I am using android with java. My data is from our backend data service. Not from Firebase. So are you mention I need to listen the message updation with the Websockets?\

Comment: Indeed, using socket.io is one good option for real-time bidirectional communication. It will do the job just like any other pub/sub model (etc. pusher, firebase cloud messaging). Going forward with socket.io, you would need to implement a socket.io server on your backend and a use a socket.io Android client on your app. socket.io-client-java is one library you can use: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java.

Comment: You can find many examples in the internet implementing a realtime architecture using socket.io. Here's two:
https://medium.com/@mrcurious/best-practices-of-socket-io-with-android-9f9cb4eb744e
https://medium.com/@mayuroks/android-mvp-realtime-architecture-with-rxjava-and-socket-io-part-1-d07e8f186468

Comment: Note that, if you rely only on WebSockets, you need to keep your app running on the background even when the user is not actively using it. But then; 1) Android can kill your process anyways, 2) even if it doesn't kill it, your app will easily drain the battery. So the best way could be to use a combination of WebSockets and FCM. When your app is running  use WebSockets, when not use FCM.

Comment: When the socket server has no connection to the socket client, it could send the message to FCM instead. Then FCM can send the message as a push notification to the client.

Comment: But it seems to I need to add this socker.io server in my backend. I need to know, without altering my backend i have to implement this realtime data with the help of recyclerview.

Comment: Unfortunately, a backend with a REST API is not enough for your use case. You need an interface enabling bidirectional communication between the server and client. Getting the messages to your recyclerview is the second step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was useful for me. I am new to implementing the chat in the native android app.

Answer (score 0):

follow this step.

**Add these to your app-module build.Gradle file:**

```
 dependencies {
    // [...]

    implementation 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

**Open the activity_main.xml generated for you replace the contents with the following:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewContents"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:id="@+id/textViewNewContents" />

</FrameLayout>

**Create a new drawable named rounded_corner and paste this:**

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**Next, let us create an adapter for the recycler view. Create a new class called RecyclerListAdapter and paste this:**

```
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView

class RecyclerListAdapter(private val listener:OnLastPositionReached): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

  private val contentList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(
       LayoutInflater
         .from(parent.context)
         .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false)
    )
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(contentList[position])

    if (position == contentList.size-1){
      listener.lastPositionReached()
    } else {
      listener.otherPosition()
    }
  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int = contentList.size

  fun addItem(item:String) {
    contentList.add(item)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }

  inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val userName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)

    fun bind(item: String) = with(itemView) {
      userName.text = item
    }
  }

  interface OnLastPositionReached {
    fun lastPositionReached()
    fun otherPosition()
  }
}
```

**Finally, open the MainActivity and set it up like so:**

```
   import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.view.View
import com.pusher.client.Pusher
import com.pusher.client.PusherOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONObject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecyclerListAdapter.OnLastPositionReached {

  private var count = 0
  private val recyclerListAdapter = RecyclerListAdapter(this)

  private var lastPosition = false
  override fun otherPosition() {
    lastPosition = false
  }

  override fun lastPositionReached() {
    lastPosition = true
    textViewNewContents.visibility = View.GONE
    count = 0
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setupClickListeners()
    setupRecyclerView()
    setupPusher()
  }
}
```

**When the textview that shows the count of the new messages is clicked, it scrolls down immediately to recent messages, set the count to 0 and hides the text view.**

**The next method is the setupRecyclerView method. Set it up like this:**

```
 private fun setupRecyclerView() {
  with(recyclerViewContents){
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    adapter = recyclerListAdapter
  }

  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Hello World")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("New article alert!")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Pusher is actually awesome")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Realtime functionality freely provided ")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Checkout pusher.com/tutorials")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("You can also checkout blog.pusher.com")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Learn how to update contents properly ")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Hello World")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("New article alert!")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Pusher is actually awesome")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Realtime functionality freely provided ")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Checkout pusher.com/tutorials")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("You can also checkout blog.pusher.com")
  recyclerListAdapter.addItem("Learn how to update contents properly ")
}
```

***The next method is the setupPusher method. Set it up like so:***

```
private fun setupPusher() {
  val options = PusherOptions()
  options.setCluster("PUSHER_CLUSTER")

  val pusher = Pusher("PUSHER_KEY", options)
  val channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel")

  channel.bind("my-event") { channelName, eventName, data ->
    runOnUiThread {  
      if (!lastPosition){
        count ++
        textViewNewContents.text = count.toString()
        textViewNewContents.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        recyclerListAdapter.addItem(JSONObject(data).getString("message"))    
      } else {
        recyclerListAdapter.addItem(JSONObject(data).getString("message"))
        recyclerViewContents.scrollToPosition(recyclerListAdapter.itemCount-1)
      } 
    }
  }

  pusher.connect()
}
```

now it's visible.

Comment: I am using java not Kotlin

Comment: Can I able to use this in this pusher in java